# Why does adding Spring AOP aspects break this asynchronous call during Spring context initialization?

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, spring-aop

I am having a hard time understanding the issue at hand, which I believe is a problem with the way how Spring proxies get created.

In this minimal example, I have two classes, `AccountLoader` and `BankImpl`, which implements an interface `Bank`. Upon start-up, `AccountLoader` executes some concurrent calls to an autowired `Bank`-instance, where the method in `BankImpl` is advised with an aspect.

In this setup the call to complete the future (`Future.get`) finishes with a `TimeoutException`, because the call appears to never terminate. However, if I call the same method before the callables get submitted to the executor, all calls finish successfully.

What is going on with Spring here? Why does this async call not terminate? And why in all seven hells does it terminate, if I add a synchronous call before the async one?

You may find the code below, a complete working example is also [available on Github](https://github.com/mtritschler/aspects-brainfuck-example)

```
public interface Bank {

    Map<String, String> getAccounts(String q);

}
```

The simple implementation

```
@Service
public class BankImpl implements Bank {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BankImpl.class);

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getAccounts(String q) {
        LOGGER.info("Listing accounts for {}", q);
        return Collections.singletonMap(q, "q");
    }

}
```

And finally the caller

```
@Service
public class AccountLoader {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AccountLoader.class);
    private final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    @Autowired
    private Bank bank;

    @PostConstruct
    public void refresh() {
        LOGGER.info("Refreshing accounts");
        // Uncommenting the following line will let the calls terminate
        // bank.getAccounts("sync");
        try {
            executorService.submit(() -> { bank.getAccounts("async"); })
                .get(5L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }

}
```

For the sake of completeness, here are the aspect

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class SomeAspect {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SomeAspect.class);

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* com.github.mtritschler.aspects.BankImpl.getAccounts(..))", returning = "returnValue")
    public Map<String, String> logCallee(Map<String, String> returnValue) {
        LOGGER.info("Result is {}", returnValue);
        return returnValue;
    }

}
```

and last but not least the configuration

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
}
```

Update: if I remove the `@EnableAspextJAutoProxy`, I also don't get an exception. Switching to load-time weaving did not change anything either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that there was a race condition between the application initialization in the main thread and the concurrent access to the injected dependency.

Once we switched the `@PostConstruct` for a listener on `ContextRefreshedEvent` it worked just fine.